# Python boto3 get cluster credentials not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, boto, boto3

I am using boto3 to retrieve temporary DbPassword for redshift using AWS IAM user account details. The password that gets generated is not correct and I get when connect to Redshift.

Invalid operation: IAM authentication failed for user

However, if I remove AWS_KEY and AWS_SECRET. It reads from the aws config file and DbPassword generated is correct and it works. I want to generate DbPassword without using Aws config file. As I need to extract DbPassword at a different server on which I cannot create this config file.

```
import json 
session = boto3.Session(region_name='region_name',
                       aws_access_key_id='AWS_KEY',
                       aws_secret_access_key='AWS_SECRET')
client = session.client('redshift')

creds = client.get_cluster_credentials(
        DbUser='user',
        DbName='db',
        ClusterIdentifier='test',
        DurationSeconds=3600,
        AutoCreate=True,
        DbGroups=['group'],
)

creds['DbPassword']
```

Answer (score 0):

It is considered bad practice to put AWS credentials in a script/program. This is because the credentials could be accidentally stored in a source code repository and get out 'in the wild'. It also makes it difficult to rotate credentials.

How you provide the credentials has no impact on whether the API call should work or not.

The fact that your code works when you *do not* have credentials embedded in the code suggests that the credentials stored in your `~.aws/credentials` file has the correct permissions, while the credentials you are inserting into the code do not have the necessary permissions.

Therefore, you should compare the credentials and determine which ones you actually wish to use.

I would recommend you **create a specific IAM User for this application**, and limit the permissions associated with the User to only what is necessary. This way, if the credentials are obtained by somebody, they are limited in what they can do.

More so, it would be better practice to **create a specific user in Amazon Redshift** via the [CREATE USER](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_USER.html) command. Then, distribute the Redshift user's password to each computer (since they'd need AWS credentials anyway, so why not just give each computer the password?).

Alternatively, use the [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) to securely make the password available to the other computers. Thus, you'd be calling the Secrets Manager rather than the `get_cluster_credentials()` API call.